# OrientDB: Create a class named 'from'

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to create an edge of class 'from' using SQL query. But it fails.
I'm guessing the 'from' confuses it with the SQL.

`CREATE CLASS from IF NOT EXISTS EXTENDS relation`
Exception:

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException:
>   Invalid script:Encountered \"  \"CREATE \"\" at line 22,
>   column 1.\nWas expecting one of:\n     ...\n    \";\" ...\n
>    ...\n    \r\n\tDB name=\"xagon\"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should backtick from:

```
CREATE CLASS `from` IF NOT EXISTS EXTENDS relation
```